# Cannot find the errors in this Pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml

The project was already created 3 years ago, and I am new to the office. I cloned the project through git. Now the pom.xml has errors :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.edm</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmao</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>gmao</name>
    <description>project for GMAO</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
             <version>8.0.13</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.3m</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
            <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
                    
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here is the build error :

```
$ mvn -X clean install -DskipTests
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 18:22:22+0300)
Maven home: D:\Logiciels\apache-maven-3.1.1\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from D:\Logiciels\apache-maven-3.1.1\apache-maven-3.1.1\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from D:\Utilisateurs\Andry\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at D:\tools\local-repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\tools\local-repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.edm:gmao:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging war from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.edm:gmao:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean, install]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gmao 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file D:\tools\local-repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-maven-plugin\1.5.8.RELEASE\spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.pom.lastUpdated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.639s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 04 10:29:13 AST 2021
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.5.8.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:265)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:190)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:198)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:108)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.5.8.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.5.8.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.pom. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:945)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:660)
        ... 4 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I m not very good at Spring , so what is wrong here ?

Comment: And we have to guess as what the errors are? Are there errors in your IDe? Doesn't the project build?

Comment: In what panel of the IDE ( Eclipse ) should I look ? The project cannot be built.

Comment: Build from where command line? Eclipse? Did you import it correctly as a maven project instead of a regular project?

Comment: I imported it as a Maven project. I build it from git bash command-line.

Comment: and it fails with? We still don't know the error or the output, please add that to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum I included the error message to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is "ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required". This means you have to change the repo URL from HTTP to HTTPS. According to your log, it's now "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" which has to be changed to "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2".

[Source](https://blog.adamgamboa.dev/2020/01/16/maven-central-repository-is-moving-to-https-and-disablig-http-access/)

EDIT: The log shows you used Maven 3.1.1. The super POM of Maven 3.6.3 already contains the HTTPS URL of Maven Central repo, so updating Maven should help.

Comment: I searched for a mention of `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` but I did not find it even in the `pom.xml` or in the `settings.xml` of maven. So where can I change it ?

Comment: Did you try to add it to the settings.xml? It should override the default.

Comment: Reinstalling maven might help. The super POM of the latest maven version (3.6.3) already contains the HTTPS URL.

Comment: I am using Maven 3.6.3; and in the menus Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings I set User setting to the settings.xml of the 3.6.3 version , so why do I still get the error ?

Comment: Also I added this to the pom.xml :
`<repositories>
  <repository>
      <id>central maven repo</id>
      <name>central maven repo https</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>`

but still get the same error !

Comment: What's the repo URL in the output of this command? `mvn help:effective-pom` You can also check the output of `mvn help:effective-settings`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229511/discussion-between-kol-and-pheromix).

Comment: I will leave office in 30 minutes, so cannot do the chat :)

Comment: for the command `mvn help:effective-pom` I get many failed downloads , the first one is `Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.2/maven-help-plugin-2.2.pom`

Comment: for the command `mvn help:effective-settings` I get many failed downloads; the first one is `Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.2/maven-help-plugin-2.2.pom`

Comment: Hmm... I tested your pom.xml on a clean machine (fresh JDK 11 install, fresh mvn 3.6.3), and your command line, `mvn -X clean install -DskipTests` ran successfully! Here is the console output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-KM3PKe2agJOBzHEiPX08ndN7IU8In2/view?usp=sharing In the end I got build error (since I have no code), but the deps could be downloaded, and the download was from the HTTPS URL, `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`, without changing anything in the POM! If I were you, I would create a clean environment (by deleting my m2 folder and reinstalling maven) and try again.

Comment: Ok , I forgot to change the PATH environment variable, it pointed to the older Maven version :) Now it works :) Thank you :)